# How can I plot data based on and ordered by date and time in python?

Tags: python, date, datetime, scatter-plot

I have two lists, one containing datetime elements and another containing numerical values. I want to plot a scatter plot in which the X axis is the date and the Y axis is the numerical value. The format of the datetime is the next: "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss".

```
datetimes = ['2015-01-10 10:00:00', '2015-01-11 10:00:00', '2015-01-10 11:00:00', '2015-01-10 10:30:00']
numerical_values = [3.0, 2.0, 10.0, 4.0]
```

How can I plot the scatter ordered by datetimes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort your lists and keep track of your coordinate doing :

```
datetimes = ['2015-01-10 10:00:00', '2015-01-11 10:00:00', '2015-01-10 11:00:00', '2015-01-10 10:30:00']
numerical_values = [3.0, 2.0, 10.0, 4.0]

x_y = sorted([(x,y) for (x,y) in zip(datetimes,numerical_values)], key=lambda z: z[0])

x = []
y = []

for X, Y in x_y:
    x.append(X)
    y.append(Y)
```